# Change DNS settings for all NIC's on Windows server through script

Tags: windows, batch-file, dns, server, windows-server-2008

I'm wanting to change the DNS settings for all adaptors on Windows servers ranging from 2008 to 2012r2.

I've written the following script, but how can I do this better AKA without needing to input adaptor names?

```
@echo off
netsh interface ipv4 set dns "Local Area Connection" static 10.20.2.72
netsh interface ipv4 add dns "Local Area Connection" 10.20.2.73 index=2
netsh interface ipv4 set dns "Ethernet" static 10.20.2.72
netsh interface ipv4 add dns "Ethernet" 10.20.2.73 index=2
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /all
set choice=
set /p choice="any interfaces still showing old DNS servers? y/n: "
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='n' exit
set /p extraint="Enter the interface name here: "
netsh interface ipv4 set dns "%extraint%" static 10.20.2.72
netsh interface ipv4 add dns "%extraint%" 10.20.2.73 index=2
ipconfig /all
ipconfig /flushdns
PAUSE
```

Comment: I think better would be with PowerShell :)

Comment: Sure, what command in powershell would do the above?

Comment: I think [this](http://mumblestiltskin.blogspot.com/2011/05/windows-add-multiple-dns-servers-to-nic.html?showComment=1314135113009#c3322198206611296079) has your answer.  It's also posted [here](http://superuser.com/questions/463096/change-dns-with-script), and has another answer with a PowerShell command, too.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it does the trick!